# Add class name to post thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm using post thumbnails to link to a page.

Is it possible to add a class name to the post thumbnail image.

```
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yep - you can pass the class you want to use to `the_post_thumbnail()` as part of the attributes argument, for example `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'your-class-name')); ?>`

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Styling_Post_Thumbnails

Comment: But this will remove the class `attachment-$size`.

Comment: But can you add the class "attachment-$size my-class-name"

Comment: @SimonCooper I did and the class now has attachment- without the size.

Comment: This is generally bad and non-generic solution. Even hardcoding attachment-$size, erases all possible future class injections.

Answer (score 15):

You can filter those classes.

```
function alter_attr_wpse_102158($attr) {
  remove_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','alter_attr_wpse_102158');
  $attr['class'] .= ' new-class';
  return $attr;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','alter_attr_wpse_102158');
```

Add the filter just before you call `the_post_thumbnail`. The filter will remove itself automatically.

It is a bit of trek to get there but [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L45) uses [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L85) which uses [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L544) which applies that filter.

Comment: Does the function name 'alter_attr_wpse_102158' have a particular meaning could this function be called myClass - function myClass($attr) {

Comment: The name is somewhat descriptive and the suffix references this question. Otherwise, no particular meaning. From inside a class instance-- say a plugin class-- you can use `array($this,'methodname')` and you can use static classes with filters by using `array('ClassName','methodname')`

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Notes

Comment: Why are you adding a filter that removes itself?

Comment: @AlxVallejo : So that it only runs once in the particular circumstance that that you want it to run.

Answer (score 1):

For most images in my websites I add a figure element around the images like below. That way I keep everything intact and still get to call the element with a class in the CSS.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <figure class="your-class">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </figure>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## May 2021

Tested and Working on **WordPress 5.7** ✔

### Default

Default `the_post_thumbnail()` will output all the required attributes from WordPress.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

<!-- DOM -->
<img 
    src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1.jpg" 
    class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" 
    alt=""
    loading="lazy" 
    srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1.jpg 1500w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-300x160.jpg 300w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-1024x546.jpg 1024w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-768x410.jpg 768w" 
    sizes="(max-width: 1500px) 100vw, 1500px" 
    width="1500" 
    height="800"
    >
```

### Using `class` array attrib.

Using the `class` without `$size` parameter or the `$size` as `thumbnail` will remove the `srcset` attribute completely. Because why do your need responsive here when you size is only `150 x 150`.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => 'classname')); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail' array('class' => 'classname')); ?>

<!-- DOM -->
<img 
    src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-150x150.jpg"
    class="classname wp-post-image"
    alt="" 
    loading="lazy"
    width="150"
    height="150"
    >
```

`srcset` will be available other than `thumbnail`. The available sizes are `thumbnail`, `medium`,  `large`, `full`. Sizes can be adjusted in your WordPress 'Dashboard > Settings > Media'

```
thumbnail:  150px
medium:     300px
large:      1024px
full:       Your original uploaded size
```

Using the `medium` as size.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('medium' array('class' => 'classname')); ?>

<!-- DOM -->
<img 
    src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-300x160.jpg" 
    class="classname img-fluid wp-post-image" 
    alt=""
    loading="lazy" 
    srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-300x160.jpg 300w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-1024x546.jpg 1024w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-768x410.jpg 768w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1.jpg 1500w" 
    sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"
    width="300"
    height="160"
    >
```

### Using the function

You can use function to include the class to the posts (function provided by @s_ha_dum). Iam adding bootstrap `img-fluid` here. Watchout! Read completely

```
// using function to add class to `the_post_thumbnail()`
function alter_attr_wpse_102158($attr) {
    remove_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','alter_attr_wpse_102158');
    $attr['class'] .= ' img-fluid';
    return $attr;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','alter_attr_wpse_102158');
```

Notice the bootstrap class `img-fluid` is added to the class attribute.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

<!-- DOM -->
<img 
    src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1.jpg" 
    class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail img-fluid wp-post-image" 
    alt="" 
    loading="lazy" 
    srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1.jpg 1500w,
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-300x160.jpg 300w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-1024x546.jpg 1024w, 
    http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/your-image-1500x800-1-768x410.jpg 768w" 
    sizes="(max-width: 1500px) 100vw, 1500px" 
    width="1500" 
    height="800"
    >
```

#### function `class` disappeared on the 2nd post

When using function, the `class` works only on the first post and it disappeared on the second one.
Use the class directly on the `the_post_thumbnail()`

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full' array('class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
```

Remember the `srcset` attribute is useless for the `thumbnail`.

Comment: Calling something like `the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => 'classname'));` will actually output a bunch of PHP Warnings. If the first parameter is an array [it expects width and height parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/#parameters). It also still outputs srcset values if the image has other sizes.

Comment: As on wp 5.7.1 it will not. Also the $size parameter is optional - (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/#parameters)

Comment: I've tried this on 5.7.1 and got srcsets as expected. The `$size` parameter may be optional but that doesn't mean you can just skip it and move onto the next parameter. If you follow the documentation through `the_post_thumbnail()` -> `get_the_post_thumbnail()` -> `wp_get_attachment_image()` it passes that array as `$size` all the way down since it's the first parameter given. Feel free to join [The Loop Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) for a broader discussion than can happen in the comments here.