# Trying to add attribute to my posts' featured image

Tags: php, posts, post-thumbnails, lightbox

I'm trying to add the attribute data-featherlight with a value of 'mylightbox' to all my post featured images. I believe this is the code I need, but I do not know where I put it. I'm working with the baseline twentyseventeen theme.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
the_post_thumbnail('post_thumbnail', array('data-featherlight'=>'mylightbox'));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to filter 'the_post_thumbnail' please follow this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134014/how-do-i-change-modify-the-post-thumbnail-html-output

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class'  => 'responsive-class' ) ); // show featured image
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### `post_thumbnail_html`

To alter the html output, you need to hook the filter [`post_thumbnail_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/)

> **From Codex:**
>
> `apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', string $html, int $post_id,
>   string $post_thumbnail_id, string|array $size, string $attr )`
>
> Filters the post thumbnail HTML.

This filter is called by `get_the_post_thumbnail`on line 177 of *post_thumbnail_template.php* after `$html` has been set with:

`$html = wp_get_attachment_image( $post_thumbnail_id, $size, false, $attr );`

Filter in context:

```
/**
* Filters the post thumbnail HTML.
     * @param string       $html              The post thumbnail HTML.
     * @param int          $post_id           The post ID.
     * @param string       $post_thumbnail_id The post thumbnail ID.
     * @param string|array $size              The post thumbnail size. Image size or array of width and height values (in that order). Default 'post-thumbnail'.
     * @param string       $attr              Query string of attributes.
*/
return

 apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', $html, $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr );
```

### Adding `data-featherlight="mylightbox"` example:

So adding your `data-featherlight="mylightbox"` would perhaps be something like:

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'my_thumbnail_filter_method', 10, 5 );
function my_thumbnail_filter_method($html, $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
     $id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
     $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, $size); 
     $alt = get_the_title($id); /
     $class = $attr['class'];

    $html = '<img src="' . $src[0] . '" alt="' . $alt . '" class="' . $class . '" data-featherlight="mylightbox" />';
}
```

---

Two other action hooks are present on either side of `$html` being set within `get_the_pos_thumbnail`.

1. `begin_fetch_post_thumbnail_html`
2. `end_fetch_post_thumbnail_html`

but both are only passing `$post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size`. 
So, it looks like filtering `post_thumbnail_html` is the best way to access the `<img>` html string.

---

A note on [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/), since it seems to come up often:
this method will return true if any images are attached to post, not specifically for the post thumbnail (aka *featured image*).

Comment: About your note: this is not true. The function has_post_thumbnail only uses the function get_post_thumbnail_id which itself ONLY looks for the specific meta value that is used by the "Featured Image", itself being _thumbnail_id.

It DOES however filter the response by using the filter "has_post_thumbnail", so if you use a theme or plugin that uses this filter to return true if there are any images attached to the post, your statement would be correct for this theme/plugin. However, that is not the "vanilla" state of wordpress.