# adding additional class to get the post thumbnail

Tags: css, post-thumbnails, array, post-class

I'm just starting to create new theme and i'm new to code. I'm stuck in customizing the post thumbnail code, i tried add

```
<?php previous_post_link(get_the_post_thumbnail(get_previous_post(), array(
                        'class' =>  'rounded-lg object-cover'
           )) . '<h4 class="text-center">%link</h4>',
           '%title',false
   );
?>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. did my array mistakenly placed in the code?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102158/add-class-name-to-post-thumbnail

Comment: Are you saying it's not working because you can't see the CSS effect you expected to see, or are you saying it's not working because the class attribute does not have those classes when you inspect the HTML?

Comment: 2nd argument is thumbnail size (usually `'post-thumbnail'`) so if you add that the attributes will shift to their correct (3rd) argument position and should be all good. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: guys sorry, i think i already fix it, and now i have problem with customizing image width and height, here are my latest code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply, already fixed, i miss understood about array, so here the code that completely run as i want it.

```
 <?php
 $next_post = get_next_post();
  next_post_link('%link',
     get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID, 'prev_next_img', array(
               'class' => 'rounded-lg object-fill w-full max-h-full' 
     )) . '<h4 class="text-center mt-2 lg:text-base text-sm no-underline text-black leading-snug font-medium">%title</h4>',                                                
     false);
 ?>
```

in function.php

i put custome image size

```
add_image_size('prev_next_img', 370, 270, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think i already fix it, and now i have problem with customizing image width and height, here are my latest code.

```
 $prev_post = get_previous_post();
 previous_post_link(
 get_the_post_thumbnail($prev_post->ID, 'custom-size-image', array(
         'class'     =>  'rounded-lg object-cover',
         'sizes'     =>  'width="371" height="270"'
 )) . '<h4 class="text-center">%link</h4>',
 '%title',
 false
 );
```

but 'sizes' part doesn't seem to work, please help

Comment: The 3rd argument is for HTML attributes, so you should be setting `'width' => 371` and `'height' => 270` separately, not `sizes`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, i'll let you know if it work

Comment: I just tried what your suggested , but return "parse error: syntax error, unexpected "height" , do i need to put comma after the number?

Comment: Yes. These are values in a [PHP array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp).

Comment: Already add it, still error, parse error:syntax error, u expected ','

Comment: Ok, sorry again, i mistakenly put ) in the middle,no more error, but width and height did not applied to the html, why?

Comment: And oh i forgot to mention, i image is lazyloaded by plugin i installed in my wordpress, does it affected to the code?

Comment: Tried to delete lazyload plugin, but still not working, how to force width number to the html, desperately need help

Comment: update your code with what you have now, what jacob suggested should work fine.